# Save WordPress templates in theme's second subdirectory

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress page where i use a lot of different WordPress page-templates. First i saved the templates just inside the theme directory but now i want to bring some order into it.

I create the templates with:

```
<?php 
     /*
    Template Name: Event - Overview
    */
?>
```

So when i save all these templates inside a subdirectory inside my theme i can select these templates for my pages. As axample i save theme inside /theme-directory/templates/template.php. But when i put them inside a second subdirectory like /theme-directory/templates/event-templates/template.php i cant select them anymore inside the WordPress Backend.

Is there a way that i can put my templates into more than just one subdirectory to bring some order into that?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have solution for you may try this, or see wordpress default themes, i have given example for twenty twenty theme.

```
get_template_part( 'templates/event-templates/template' );
```

for the file name dont use extension.
Please follow the link i given as screenshot https://prnt.sc/spe1qt

You can create as many directory as you want, that is not a problem at all